# How to alter this vbscript to create sub-folders

Tags: vbscript

I have a working vbscript that creates a group of folders in a directory chosen by the user on a windows 2008 r2 server. I want to modify it to create additional sub-folders within the primary folders being created. I'm googled out and need advice.
Here is the working script:

```
' 26Apr2015 jkw -- q&d

Option Explicit

Dim g_fso:  Set g_fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim tgt: tgt = BrowseFolder(".", False)


Dim subdirs:  subdirs = Array(_
"Accounting",_
"Anchors",_
"Approvals",_
"Bid Documents",_
"Engineering",_
"Mold Drawings",_
"Plans and Specs",_
"Revisions and Cost Changes",_
"Shops",_
"Transmittals"_
)

Dim subdir
For Each subdir in subdirs
    WScript.Echo g_fso.CreateFolder(tgt & "\" & subdir)
Next

Function BrowseFolder( myStartLocation, blnSimpleDialog )
' This function generates a Browse Folder dialog
' and returns the selected folder as a string.
'
' Arguments:
' myStartLocation   [string]  start folder for dialog, or "My Computer", or
'                             empty string to open in "Desktop\My Documents"
' blnSimpleDialog   [boolean] if False, an additional text field will be
'                             displayed where the folder can be selected
'                             by typing the fully qualified path
'
' Returns:          [string]  the fully qualified path to the selected folder
'
' Based on the Hey Scripting Guys article
' "How Can I Show Users a Dialog Box That Only Lets Them Select Folders?"
' http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/jun05/hey0617.mspx
'
' Function written by Rob van der Woude
' http://www.robvanderwoude.com
    Const MY_COMPUTER   = &H11&
    Const WINDOW_HANDLE = 0 ' Must ALWAYS be 0

    Dim numOptions, objFolder, objFolderItem
    Dim objPath, objShell, strPath, strPrompt

    ' Set the options for the dialog window
    strPrompt = "Select a folder in which to create subdirectories:"
    If blnSimpleDialog = True Then
        numOptions = 0      ' Simple dialog
    Else
        numOptions = &H10&  ' Additional text field to type folder path
    End If

    ' Create a Windows Shell object
    Set objShell = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )

    ' If specified, convert "My Computer" to a valid
    ' path for the Windows Shell's BrowseFolder method
    If UCase( myStartLocation ) = "MY COMPUTER" Then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace( MY_COMPUTER )
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
        strPath = objFolderItem.Path
    Else
        strPath = myStartLocation
    End If

    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder( WINDOW_HANDLE, strPrompt, _
                                              numOptions, strPath )

    ' Quit if no folder was selected
    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        BrowseFolder = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Retrieve the path of the selected folder
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
    objPath = objFolderItem.Path

    ' Return the path of the selected folder
    BrowseFolder = objPath
End Function
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
For Each subdir in subdirs
    set subdirnew = g_fso.CreateFolder(tgt & "\" & subdir)
    'then repeat for your other folders
    g_fso.CreateFolder(subdirnew.path & "\" & subsubdir)
Next
```

Comment: Should I try this without changing the array as suggested below?

Comment: Nice try Trigger! Appreciate the effort nonetheless :~)

Comment: My way requires an extra variable called subsubdir. You should use whichever of the two patterns shown here is simplist for your task.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add them to your list like so:

```
Dim subdirs:  subdirs = Array(_
"Accounting",_
"Anchors",_
"Approvals",_
"Approvals\NewFolder",_
"Approvals\NewFolder\Something",_
"Approvals\AnotherFolder",_
"Bid Documents",_
"Engineering",_
"Mold Drawings",_
"Plans and Specs",_
"Revisions and Cost Changes",_
"Shops",_
"Transmittals"_
)
```

Just make sure they are in order for example you cannot have Approvals\NewFolder\Something before Approvals\NewFolder as Approvals\NewFolder will not be created yet.

Comment: This alone doesn't get it done. It generates an error "file already exists".

Comment: My mistake--I had forgotten to delete the folders from previous trials. With an empty directory it generates a line 28 char 5 variable is undefined "subdirnew" error. This is coming from Trigger's code addition.

Comment: After removing Trigger's suggestions, Dan's code works. Ughh... all my fault for forgetting to delete those folders. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: One more minor issue. After selecting the chosen directory in which to create the folders, the user is presented with a dialogue with an "OK" button for every folder creation. As I said, it's minor, but I know my end user is going to complain about needing to click OK numerous times. Can we make it just a single OK confirmation? I like the idea of making the user stop and check their location, but once is sufficient, right?

Comment: It's because you are using WScript.Echo Echo tells it to "Echo" the result to the screen. I am not really down with VBS but you "should" be able to just delete the echo command perhaps?

Comment: Use `If (g_fso.FolderExists(tgt & "\" & subdir)) Then WScript.Echo g_fso.CreateFolder(tgt & "\" & subdir)` to prevent `file already exists`  error. Use `Popup` method with a suitable `nSecondsToWait` argument instead of `Echo` (or launch your script using `cscript` instead of `wscript` host).

Comment: Ok, removing wscript.echo got rid of all the "ok" prompts. Now, one last issue: How can I make the File Explorer open up to a pre-determined directory. My users (heaven help me) would like to drill down less. Would changing `Dim tgt: tgt = BrowseFolder(".", False)` to `Dim tgt: tgt = BrowseFolder("predeterminedpath", False)` do it? Testing now.

Comment: Yep, it worked. Sorry, I should have just tested my idea before posting :~)

Comment: UH OH... major issue just discovered. If the user cancels the file explorer, the folders still get created  in whatever directory file explorer opened to. That's not good, and I have no idea how to stop it from happening.